# Use success and error in angular service or controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, separation-of-concerns

I created an angular service contains this code:

```
authenticationAPI.login = function() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                timeout: 10000,
                url:'http://serverName/apiName/Login',
                params : {userName : 'User',
                          password : '12345'}
            });
```

So , currently my "authenticationController" is using the "login" method of this service and handling the .success and .error by itself.

One of the reasons i chose to handle it inside the controller is to decide what to do with the html (show alert, change some elements) from the controller when encounter an error for example.

But, i am new to angular and not sure if this is the best practice for handling the request.

Can you help me figure out if i should handle this logic in the service or controller?

Comment: Personally, I have done the same as you - returned the promise and handled the result somewhere where it makes sense to display the result to the user. I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: The thing is..i tried to read about it and could not find a descriptive post that talks about the best practices for that.
And i would be happy to know if the way i chose is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends on what is entailed with handling the logic of the deferred.  I have done both - let the service handle the deferred and let the controller handle the deferred.  I think a deciding factor should be:

Is the deferred logic something that would update the view/UI?  Then handle it in the controller

Is the deferred logic something that would update data that would otherwise be used by other providers or controllers?  Then handle it in the service.

In your case, it sounds like its view logic that needs handled, so I think the controller is fine.

Comment: So generally, you say that it is not black and white.
You say that in the same angular application it is fine to handle the promise sometimes in controller and in other cases in service.
It is not have to be always on controller or always on service in the same app?

Comment: In my opinion, yes.  Nothing is ever really black or white.  I've done it using both approaches myself in many apps.